# Ubuntu Dual Boot App (Android) crashes on boot since 4.4.3 update

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

I updated my Android Nexus 4 to 4.4.3, followed the dual boot instructions to install the dual boot app, but every time i open it it crashes right away. Does any one know how to work around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can re run the dualboot.sh script? You should install FULL version, since apparently after the android upgrade the supersu app is lost and the the dualboot app can't get sudo access. Hope this helps